# Can a language have a multiple solution in dfa diagram?

Tags: dfa

What i mean is that can there be multiple different forms of diagram of the same language? Can it be drawn with multiple solutions? Or each language has only one solution in DFA? I attended a pop quiz today. Drew a solution and tried multiple strings. Each of those were accepted but i didn't get any points for it. Didn't get any feedback from my TA as why it was considered wrong.
The question was. Let L = {w | w contains an odd number of 0s or at least two 1s}.
This is what i did (sorry had to use ms paint).[image]

Comment: Will that accept "0101"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice a bit more carefully then 0101 is a string in your language but it is not accepted by your automata. Also to answer your other question, yes, there can be multiple DFAs which accept the same language. A trivial example would be the language 0* (Think about it if you are still interested, haha!).

P.S. - Just noticed a comment which pointed out the counter-example but I still went ahead. Sorry!